# Eslint padded-blocks: ["error", { "blocks": "never" }] not working

Tags: eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

my eslint definition is:

`padded-blocks: ["error", { "blocks": "never" }]`

and my code is:

```
Vue.directive('confirm', {
  bind(el, binding) {
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {
...
```

But I'm still getting:

```
✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/padded-blocks  Block must not be padded by blank lines
   src/directives/confirm.js:6:40
     el.addEventListener('click', () => {
```

Is it some bug?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your example correctly then it should be

```
padded-blocks: ["error", { "blocks": "always" }]
```

Comment: Ok, than I have understand it reversed.
Thanks